# How to imitate servers (without loss of computing power)?

Tags: simulation

I have production environment, which is running on one server. But I need to run 2 instances of one software, each on "another" server.

Is it possible to imitate more servers on one real server for free? Without loss of computing power and network flow in/out of the real server?

EDIT:
In another words: I want to run two instances of the same software on one machine.
And then I need to use some function that transport some subinstance from instance1 into instance2. But this function is only possible to use when instance1 is on another server than instance2. So I need to imitate that one of both instances running on local is on different servers.

Comment: Hypervisor based VMs should be pretty efficient. At least if you don't need graphics cards or special hardware.

Comment: I have only one license. I need to imitate that two instances of the same software are running on different servers.

Comment: Licensing is more of a legal question than a technical question. The question is what your software license allows, in particular if a single license may be used in two virtual machines at the same time.

Comment: i do not need more licences, i need to imitate that one instance is running on another server.

Comment: And why can't you just start multiple instances of the software on one machine? You should start in the beginning, describing what you actually want to achieve, and what limits the license poses. Many licenses won't allow you to run the software on two virtual machines at the same time, even if they're on the same physical machine.

Comment: I do NOT need to run software on two virtual machines. I need that one instance of the software is looking on another instance of the same software on the same server like it is on another server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making an assumption that you are using Windows, in which case you could use a Hypervisor like Hyper-V however if you have only purchased one license of Windows you may be fairly limited in what you can run in a production capacity.

If you mean that the software you need to run only has one license you typically are not allowed to virtualize it either, so it seems like the answer is legally you are not going to be able to do much with just one license, however my assumptions may be all wrong, your question wasn't clear enough.

Comment: I do not need to virtualize it. I need IMITATE that one instance is running on another server, it is due to some "features" of the software that are only aviable for instance on remote server, not local server.

Comment: In other words, I need to use some function on local instance of my application, that is applicable only on remote instance of my application.

Comment: Read the comment from @CodeInChaos above, we need a bit more information on what you are expecting the setup to do. Imitate could mean a lot of different things.

Comment: And if that's the case I don't know of any way to make the application appear to be running on another machine without actually making that happen.